# cannot assign tf.numpy_function result to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to assign the return value of `get_value()` to a numpy array within a method decorated using `tf.function`. It works only if I call the method directly. However, if I use the result of `tf.numpy_function()` (in `case3`), I get an error.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.storage = np.zeros((10, 3, 1))

    @staticmethod
    def get_value():
        return np.array([[1], [2], [3]])

    @tf.function
    def case1(self):  # works
        self.storage[0] = self.get_value()

    def case2(self):  # works
        self.storage[0] = tf.numpy_function(self.get_value, inp=[], Tout=tf.float32)

    @tf.function  # fails
    def case3(self):
        self.storage[0] = tf.numpy_function(self.get_value, inp=[], Tout=tf.float32)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.case1()
    foo.case2()
    foo.case3()
```

It works for all except `case3()` and raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emadboctor/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 29, in <module>
    foo.case3()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3887, in bound_method_wrapper
    return wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:

    /Users/emadboctor/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3/scratches/scratch.py:22 case3  *
        self.storage[0] = tf.numpy_function(self.get_value, inp=[], Tout=tf.float32)

    TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you get from `tf.numpy_function()`

Comment: code works better if I use `return np.array([[1], [2], [3]], dtype='float32')` in `get_value()`. As for me problem can be because you use one `tf` function inside another `tf` function and probably it needs correct values in data. It will not optimize it for you. Maybe `tf` didn't expect it. Or maybe it need different method to run one `tf` function inside another `tf` function.

Comment: @furas I get a `Tensor("PyFunc:0", dtype=float32, device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0)` any ideas?

Comment: @furas and regarding using `tf.function` inside another, as far as I understand `tf.numpy_function` allows functions that perform numpy operations to be executed within tensorflow graph, it shouldn't introduce conflicts when executed in `tf.function`.